# Ajax Server Call Success but go to error area

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I use spring boot and jquery.

I do an ajax call.

```
 var memberId = $('#memberId').val();
 var type = "put";
 var url = getHostName() + "/members/" + memberId + "/payments/" + paymentsId + "/process/" + paymentMode;
 jQuery.ajax({
     type: type,
     url: url,
     contentType: "application/json",
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
         loadMemberPaymentTable(templateMemberPayment, memberId);
     },
     error: function (jqXHR, status) {
         check401Unauthorized(jqXHR);
     }
 });
```

This controller is called, and in error is called

```
 jqXHR = Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}, status = "parsererror"
```

dont know if its' the spring thing who is the problem or not

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/members/{memberId}/payments/{paymentsId}/process/{paymentMode}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public ResponseEntity<Void> processPayment(@PathVariable("memberId") Long memberId, @PathVariable("paymentsId") List<Long> paymentsId, @PathVariable("paymentMode") PaymentModeEnum paymentMode) {
        paymentService.processPayment(paymentsId, paymentMode);
    return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Edit

Url called is
http://localhost:8080/rest/members/6/payments/100,101/process/CASH

if i return a value from my controller... that work
So it's seem the problem it's spring...

Don't seem to be the correct way, to return no value.

process can work or fail... so what is the correct way to send this to the client?

maybe there is something from spring boot to manage that?

Comment: Would it be possible to post the final URL that your are hitting, specifically the Enum and paymentIds part -  do scrub the host if necessary.

Comment: i edited the question and answered your question.

Comment: I'd first try logging  the arguments before sending them to processPayment and put the processPayment in a try catch block, with the catch returning a 500 and logging the exception being thrown. the Http.OK would be send only if there's no error.